Why does Matplotlib draw a weird line when the marker='o' is specified?
So I am trying to draw an axe and plot it with Matplotlib, but when plotting, this weird line forms between the last point of blade1_x and the first point of blade2_x.
Can anyone explain why?
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_axe_points(num_points=100):
    # Handle 1
    handle1_x = np.linspace(0.5, 1, num_points // 2)
    handle1_y = np.full(handle1_x.shape, 1)

    handle2_y = np.linspace(1, 5, num_points // 2)
    handle2_x = np.full(handle2_y.shape, 0.5)

    handle3_x = np.linspace(0.5, 1, num_points // 2)
    handle3_y = np.full(handle3_x.shape, 5)

    handle4_y = np.linspace(1, 5, num_points // 2)
    handle4_x = np.full(handle4_y.shape, 1)
    
    # Blade
    blade1_x = np.linspace(1, 4, num_points // 2)
    blade1_y = 0.05 * blade1_x ** 2 - 0.2 * blade1_x + 5.15

    blade2_x = np.linspace(1, 4, num_points // 2)
    blade2_y = -0.05 * blade2_x ** 2 + 0.2 * blade2_x + 3.5


    
    x = np.concatenate([handle1_x, handle2_x, handle3_x, handle4_x, blade1_x, blade2_x])
    y = np.concatenate([handle1_y, handle2_y, handle3_y, handle4_y, blade1_y, blade2_y])
    
    return list(zip(x, y))

axe_points = generate_axe_points()

# Plot the original axe
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.plot(*zip(*axe_points), 'b-', marker = 'o')
plt.title("Original Axe Shape")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()

Here is result

Why is this line surprising? blade1 and blade2 aren't separate plots, since you're concatenating everything together.  The last point of 1 is connected to the first point of 2 with a line, just like every other pair of consecutive points gets connected with a line.  Reversing the blade2_x and blade2_y arrays would at least make the line a useful part of the axe shape.

To add to the good answers you already have, note that the "weird line" you are talking about is only there because you requested it: the format specifier 'b-' is stating the colour should be blue (b) and there should be a solid line connecting the points (-). If you only want the markers, and no line, don't ask for the line! plt.plot(*zip(*axe_points), color='b', marker='o', linestyle='None')

This is because you have concatenated everything into a single array- with the blade1 coordinates immediately adjacent to the blade2 coordinates. The quick fix is to insert a numpy.nan between adjacent coordinates that you do not want to be visually linked:
def generate_axes_points(num_points=100):
    ... # code above this point remains the same

    # Add `np.nan` between the blade1 & blade2
    x = np.concatenate([handle1_x, handle2_x, handle3_x, handle4_x, blade1_x, [np.nan], blade2_x])
    y = np.concatenate([handle1_y, handle2_y, handle3_y, handle4_y, blade1_y, [np.nan], blade2_y])

    return list(zip(x, y))



axe_points = generate_axe_points()

# Plot the original axe
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.plot(*zip(*axe_points), 'b-', marker = 'o')
plt.title("Original Axe Shape")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()


Perhaps another solution would be to create each "piece" of the axe separately and plot them individually:
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_points = 100
handle1_x = np.linspace(0.5, 1, num_points // 2)
handle1_y = np.full(handle1_x.shape, 1)

handle2_y = np.linspace(1, 5, num_points // 2)
handle2_x = np.full(handle2_y.shape, 0.5)

handle3_x = np.linspace(0.5, 1, num_points // 2)
handle3_y = np.full(handle3_x.shape, 5)

handle4_y = np.linspace(1, 5, num_points // 2)
handle4_x = np.full(handle4_y.shape, 1)

# Blade
blade1_x = np.linspace(1, 4, num_points // 2)
blade1_y = 0.05 * blade1_x ** 2 - 0.2 * blade1_x + 5.15

blade2_x = np.linspace(1, 4, num_points // 2)
blade2_y = -0.05 * blade2_x ** 2 + 0.2 * blade2_x + 3.5

# avoids repeated calls to zip and array concatenation
coordinate_pairs = [
    (handle1_x, handle1_y),
    (handle2_x, handle2_y),
    (handle3_x, handle3_y),
    (handle4_x, handle4_y),
    (blade1_x,  blade1_y),
    (blade2_x,  blade2_y),
]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
for xs, ys in coordinate_pairs:
    ax.plot(xs, ys, color='b', marker='o', ls='-')
    ax.set_title('Original Axe Shape')
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()



I like your second solution, thx <3
